# Error while using google play services lib to implement ads in my app

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services, ubuntu-14.04

Helo guys. I'm trying to implement some ads in my app and both of them needs google play services lib. The point is, when I import that lib to my project it just freeze my Eclipse and start to show many dialogue windows about an error. I'm using Eclipse Standard/SDK Version:

**Luna Release (4.4.0) Build id: 20140612-0600**

with the android sdk updated on **Ubuntu 14.04.** I already tried to change the memory values at `eclipse.ini` to 512M ans 1024M but it didn't solve the issue. I've found many people discussing about this error and none of that answers gave me a solution. Follows the error message shown after the lib import:

```
[2014-07-22 00:23:37 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded

[2014-07-22 00:23:37 - AppName] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Play Services Has Tons of Classes and DEX does not support unlimited Classes, it Might be related to that.

Here is a blog post how to implement custom class Loading, maybe that will point you into the right direction. http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html

Maybe you should consider trying to compile it via console or an alternative IDE like Android Studio (wich is imo way better than eclipse).

Comment: Many thanks Angelo, I`m gonna try Android Studio and post the results asap.

Comment: Helo again Angelo, sorry for the delay. I found what was getting me stuck on the compilation step. I had a copy of Google Play Services lib inside my workspace and imported from there. After delete that folder, place that out of my workspace and imported again with "copy projects to my workspace" checked it worked perfectly. Thanks again for your time.